# Position an UISwitch in sprite-kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uikit

I would like know how to position a UISwitch programmatically in my sprite-kit scene. Is there an `.position` property like SKSpritenodes have or something like that ?

Code:

```
UISwitch *vibrateSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
vibrateSwitch.on = YES;
[vibrateSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(vibrateSwitch:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:vibrateSwitch];
```

(code in objective-c please)

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed (judging from your tags), SpriteKit and UIKit are two different UI setups that are not interchangeable.

I think you can just set the UISwitch's frame x and y position (should be the first two values).  Keep in mind though, that SpriteKit and UIKit are different coordinate spaces, so you should be able to access the view's `frame` size something like this:

```
self.view.frame.size
```

Note this is different from the SpriteKit scene size, which I think you can pull like this:

```
self.frame.size
```